# django - import different module when variable change

Tags: python, django

I wanna import different module as the variable a changed.

```
#views.py
path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(here, 'module/%s' % a))
sys.path.append(path)
from foo import bar
sys.path.remove(path)
```

And my folder show as below:

```
djangoapp---module----a----index.py & __init.py
              |-------b----index.py & __init.py
              views.py
```

I doing this way is worked, but is there any other way to switch the module when the variable a changed?

My friend tell me it's better not to modify the content of the sys.path during the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instad of fiddling with the sys.path, you can just import from a different location, like:

```
module_name = 'a.foo'
module = __import__(module_name, globals(), locals(), ['*'])
```

See more in the docs to [__import__](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

Maybe [importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) will be even a better choice.